# Is there a way to transform an image texture after it has been created using Cycles shader nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I want to transform an image after it has been created, like the compositing Distort nodes. However, I cannot seem to find an equivalent in shader nodes. I need to transform the Color output of the Texture node.

I am trying to create a Node Group that takes a procedural image and "symmetrize" it. This basically takes one procedural image Color output as an input, cuts it in half, and combines the half with its mirror. Because I only want one procedural image input, I need to find a way to flip the Color input, and I cannot access the Vector input of the procedural image from inside the Node Group.

This is a prototype of what I am looking for:
[image: Transform Image node prototype]

Is there a way to do this in Blender, or is it not possible?

Comment: could you add an image of your problem, I am having a hard time imagining what is going on.

Comment: @Michael Alright, I added an image, please do tell me if more clarification is needed.

Comment: What is the reason you can't use the texture coordinate and mapping nodes?

Comment: I am still fuzzy on what visual effect you are trying to do. are you trying to rotate the image on the texture or are you trying to replicate some of the other distort effects?

Comment: @Michael I added more clarification. Again, please do tell me if I need to add more details.

Comment: The problem is that pixel color information is stored in a sequence. it assumes the image is built left to right, top to bottom. the mapping node adds positional information to the pixels. in order to make the changes, you want to make you need to scale that information by -1 for the image flip to take place. you also need it to get the greater than function to split the image and merge it. without that positional information, there is no way to adjust it that I know of. To my knowledge, you would at the very least need the generated coordinates as an input.